# Solve for all the complex numbers $z$ that satisfy $\overline{\sin(iz)} = \sin(i\overline{z})$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Please help me solve the the problem as follows:

Solve for all the complex numbers $z$ that satisfy $\overline{\sin(iz)} = \sin(i\overline{z})$.

Comment: Do you know/can you show that for all $w\in \mathbb{C}$ we have $\overline{\sin w} = \sin \overline{w}$?

Answer (score 0):

$\overline{\sin(iz)}=\sin(-i\overline{z})=-\sin(i\overline{z})$. Thus $\sin(i\overline{z})=0$, and you know how t0 continue from here.